# Inserting a document in a bottom of a reversing array in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I have the next publication with a sorting by created date

```
Messages.find({ request: id, }, { limit: 3, sort: { createdAt: -1 } })
```

and I get: 5 → 4 → 3

On client I use the reverse

```
Messages.find().fetch().reverse()
```

and respectively I get: 3 → 4 → 5

When I use a method for inserting in the collection, a new document puts in a beginning of an array.  If I don’t use a reverse, all is good – a document puts in a bottom, but I want a reversing array. By the way, use “$hint” in a Mongo method – it's not a solution, because it’s works only if a number of documents the less than the options limit.

that’s I get: 6 → 3 → 4 but I **want**: 4 → 5 → 6

Comment: Just use `{ limit: 3, sort: { createdAt: 1 }}` in your client side query and eliminate the `.reverse()`. It will be just as fast and you won't have this problem.

Comment: @MichelFloyd I don't know why, but if I use options on the client  `Messages.find({}, { limit, sort: { createdAt: -1 } }).fetch().reverse()` - all works as I want. Thank you!

Comment: `.reverse()` inverts the `sort -1` so it's a bit redundant.

Comment: @MichelFloyd Could you explain me, how I can get this solution without use the reverse function? I want to get last documents with a limit, but in a reverse order (if use only `sort: { createdAt: -1 }` in options)

Comment: If you have documents 1,2,3,4,5,6 do you want 6,5,4 or 3,2,1?

Comment: @MichelFloyd I want 4, 5, 6. If I'll use only 'sort', I'll get 6, 5, 4.

Comment: ok, now I understand.